# Why misspelled android:name do not have a warning or error?

Tags: android

I hava a receiver

```
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```

But the receiver's class name is AlarmReciver (misspelled)

why android-sdk show this mistake or show this when running?

Comment: Why on earth was this closed?  This is a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that class is loaded by [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), so compiler doesn't know that class doesn't exist (for the compiler, this a `String`, not a class name). When the JVM will attempt to load that class by reflection, it should throw a `ClassNotFoundException` indicating there's no such class.

Comment: I don't think Android will even throw a CNFE for a BroadcastReceiver... which can be _frustrating_.

Comment: @Sam I edited to "should" instead of "will" :P Android is **FULL** of annoying/frustrating stuff (check Parcelable or Fragment wonderful world :P) and many very poorly designed API classes.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question. This kind of check can be easily done in the compile time and it's already done by many `IDE`'s. `Intellij IDEA` shows such a type of errors by default, `Eclipse` allows you to run  `Android Lint` (right click on the project -> Android Tools -> Run Lint) that finds this error as well.

Comment: Then he doesn't use IntelliJ and he didn't run LINT on his project to check that. If you have a better answer please feel free to post it.

Comment: @vmironov also I don't see how this don't answer the question. Please check the question again: *"**WHY** misspelled android:name do not have a warning or error?"*, not *"how to make it show the error"*.